# wrap a wide image into several lines

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, word-wrap

I'm producing a rather wide image, listing consecutive training sessions of target practice.

[image]

At present, this is not very helpful graphic and I will need to get the image wrapped into several lines to make data for each training set more visible. So far I've been managing this by introducing a second variable that denotes the line into which a training set belongs to. The draw back is that now I have a strip above each row that serves little to no purpose.

[image]

Another way of doing this would be to generate each line as a seperate figure and merge them using `gridExtra`'s `grid.arrange`.

I'm looking for other (elegant) ways of wrapping a wide figure to multiple rows. I would like to have no strip above each facet, if possible. All suggestions welcome.

This is the code I used to generate these images.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

st <- 23 # number of training sets
sk <- 10 # number of shots per training set
dt <- sample(7:10, size = st * sk, prob = c(0.005, 0.15, 0.195, 0.65), replace = TRUE)
rslt <- as.data.frame(matrix(dt, nrow = 10))
names(rslt) <- paste("trening", seq_len(ncol(rslt)), sep = "")

rsltm <- melt(rslt, variable.name = "trening", value.name = "rezultat")
rsltm$trening <- ordered(rsltm$trening) 

n <- 5 # number of trainings per row
st.vrst <- round(st/n)
vrsta <- paste("vrsta", seq_len(st.vrst), sep = "")

rsltm$vrsta <- rep(vrsta, each = sk * n, length.out = nrow(rsltm))
rm(vrsta)

# wide figure
ggplot(rsltm, aes(x = trening, y = rezultat)) + 
   geom_dotplot(binaxis  = "y", stackdir = "center", show_guide = FALSE) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = rep("red", st)) +
   theme_bw()

# wrapped figure
ggplot(rsltm, aes(x = trening, y = rezultat, fill = trening)) + 
   geom_dotplot(binaxis  = "y", stackdir = "center", show_guide = FALSE) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = rep("red", st)) +
   facet_wrap(~vrsta, nrow = st.vrst, scales = "free_x") +
   theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove strip texts above the small plots you can set `elemnt_blank()` for those elements.

```
# wrapped figure
ggplot(rsltm, aes(x = trening, y = rezultat, fill = trening)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis  = "y", stackdir = "center", show_guide = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep("red", st)) +
  facet_wrap(~vrsta, nrow = st.vrst, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.text=element_blank(),
                     strip.background=element_blank())
```

#### EDIT - update of produced plot

One way to improve plot could be placing of `trening` labels inside the plot region.

For this purpose new data frame `df.names` is made. Number of rows correspond to levels of `trening`.

```
df.names<-data.frame(lab.nam=unique(rsltm$trening), #labels
       x=rep(1:5, times = 5, length.out = 23), #x coordinate (1:5)
       y=rep(11,23), #y coordinate (11)
       vrsta=rep(vrsta, each = 5, length.out = 23)) #vrsta values to ensure position in facets
```

Code to produce plot without x axis labels. `panel.margin=` ensures that space between facets is smaller.

```
p <- ggplot(rsltm, aes(x = trening, y = rezultat)) + 
      geom_dotplot(binaxis  = "y", stackdir = "center", show_guide = FALSE) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = rep("red", st)) +
      facet_wrap(~vrsta, nrow = st.vrst, scales = "free_x") +
      theme_bw() + theme(strip.text=element_blank(),
                     strip.background=element_blank(),
                     panel.margin = unit(-0.6, "lines"),
                     panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(7.5,11.5),breaks=c(8,9,10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

With `geom_text()` place labels above dots.

```
p +  geom_text(data=df.names,aes(x, y, label=lab.nam),size=4)
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my solution with new plot.